# How to create a temporary model dynamically in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, model

I have a Rails model `MyModel`

While loading data into a JQuery datatable from `MyModel`, I'd like to run the following query and feed the results of this query to the datatable:

```
SELECT child.*
FROM   my_models      AS child
LEFT   JOIN my_models AS parent ON parent.id = child.parent_id
ORDER  BY COALESCE(parent.id, child.id)  
        , parent.id IS NOT NULL          
        , child.id;
```

1. Is there a way I can create a temporary model that'd run the above query on `MyModel` and feed the temporary model to the datatable instead of `MyModel`
   ?
2. If `1.` is not feasible, then is there a way to create a new model by just cloning `MyModel` and load the results of the above query in the new model (copy all columns and retain the types)?

### UPDATE:

This is what my datatable looked like when it WAS working:

```
    my_models = MyModel.joins(:sequence_number,:account).order("#{sort_column} #{@tabular.sort_direction}")
    my_models = my_models.limit(page_length).offset(@tabular.offset)
    my_models = my_models.where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date = ?", @tabular.search_date);
    my_models = my_model_method1(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method2(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method3(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method4(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method6(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method7(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method8(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method9(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method10(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method11(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method12(my_models)
```

I changed it to include my query in it and it stopped working after that:

```
 sort_column = SORTABLE_COLUMNS[@tabular.sort_column]
    my_models = MyModel.find_by_sql("SELECT child.* FROM my_models AS child LEFT JOIN my_models AS parent ON concat('OVER_', parent.id::text) = child.replacement_record_id OR concat('NET_', parent.id::text) = child.replacement_record_id ORDER BY COALESCE(parent.id, child.id), parent.id IS NOT NULL, child.id").joins(:sequence_number,:account).order("#{sort_column} #{@tabular.sort_direction}")
    my_models = my_models.limit(page_length).offset(@tabular.offset)
    my_models = my_models.where("sequence_numbers.as_of_date = ?", @tabular.search_date);
    my_models = my_model_method1(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method2(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method3(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method4(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method6(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method7(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method8(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method9(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method10(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method11(my_models)
    my_models = my_model_method12(my_models)
```

Pls help!

Comment: You can create a poro(Plain Old Ruby Object) that has that query in a method. Then just call that.  `Poro.create_my_model_query`

Comment: Would I be able to feed that poro instance to a jQuery datatable? I feel probably not. I have a datatable that is currently working fine. I tried using `find_by_sql` on my model and am feeding the result of that `find_by_sql` to my datatable. My datatable won't load as soon as I made that change. Looks like datatables expect a model and not poro.

Comment: Can you show us the view code where you are rendering the datatable

Comment: I have posted an "UPDATE:" section in my original question and have explained what the datatable code looked like before and after I included my query in it.